# Trouble installing Facebook-iOS-SDK 3.1.1 in Rubymotion

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, rubymotion

I'm trying to install the Facebook-iOS-SDK to my RubyMotion project but have hit a few hurdles.

According to section 5 of the [Getting Started Instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) I should include the FacebookSDK framework and SQLite3.

I know how to do these in XCode but have no idea when it comes to Rubymotion - can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend including it using CocoaPods via the motion-cocoapods gem.

Add motion-cocoapods to your Rakefile:

```
require 'motion-cocoapods'
```

In your app setup, add this:

```
app.pods do
  dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
end
```

Also include the sqlite library thusly:

```
app.libs += ['/usr/lib/libz.dylib', '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib']
```

Add this right below your frameworks:

```
app.weak_frameworks += %w{ AdSupport Accounts Social }
```

Do a `rake clean` and then build again and you should have it installed. Oh, and probably `gem install motion-cocoapods` or drop it into your Gemfile if you're using bundler.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using cocoapods already but kept getting errors - I didn't know about including the libs but I've managed to get it working by adding this to my Rakefile: `app.weak_frameworks += %w{ AdSupport Accounts Social }`

Answer (score 0):

A few people were having a problem with this so I wrote a blog post detailing the steps:

[How To Use the Facebook iOS SDK In Your RubyMotion project](http://gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/30-how-to-use-the-facebook-ios-sdk-in-your-rubymotion-project)

Thanks again to Jamon Holmgren for pointing me in the right direction!